# Trying to turn on flash light, don't get torch capability

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mediastream

I am trying to turn on flash on a web application running in chrome under windows 10, Panasonic tablet.

According to tutorials i should get torch true when calling track.getCapabilities()

However i dont get torch at all in the returning object.
Native apps are able to turn on the flash light.

See code:

```
video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
            video.play();
            setTimeout(() => {
                const track = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                const capabilities = typeof track.getCapabilities === 'function' && track.getCapabilities() || {};
                if (capabilities.torch) {
                  hasTorchMode = true;
                }
              }, 250);
          };
```

Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML as without it we could be speculating and in doing so wont be very helpful to you. Also, your narrowing your viewers down, as getCapabilities is not universally supported throughout all browsers including Fireforx, IE, Safari and Samsung (mobile web browser)

Comment: <video ng-show="videoMode" class="videoPic video-container" id="picsvideo" width="1155" height="570" autoplay></video>

Comment: Also when running the following code:imageCapture.takePhoto({ fillLightMode:"flash" })
                    .then(blob => {
                        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        img.onload = () => { URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); }
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error('Uh, oh, takePhoto() error:', error));The flash still doesn't work